# How to better understand/calculate runtime complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, big-o

I'm a freshman in college and we're currently studying runtime complexity/worst-case complexity using Big O. I understand the concept perfectly fine, what I struggle with is applying it and actually determining the runtime complexity of certain algorithms. For example, I've never found an algorithm of complexity O(NlogN) during my own work or practice, but then it'll come up in quizzes/tests and burn me. Any tips for how to improve my skills at determining runtime complexity of algorithms?

Comment: `O(n * log n)` might be a linear scan through an array where you check each item against a binary tree. For example, you already have the tree with the people for lookup and you want to find all the people in it (or *not* in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a CS course on algorithms and data structures, you will encounter many different algorithms and their complexities. This will give you a good basis for quickly spotting the complexities of algorithms in "real life".

You specifically mentioned O(N log N). This is actually a very common complexity that comes up in divide-and-conquer algorithms that scans all items in a list before recursing on both halves of the list, e.g. Quicksort or Mergesort. But it also frequently occurs in non-recursive code.  Here is a simple example with complexity O(n log n) in pseudocode:

```
function(int n):
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      print(i);
```